# Speed up calculating sum of cartesian products

Tags: python-3.x, sum, cartesian-product

I failed several test cases for an automated screening exam because my code ran too long. Is there a way to write this more efficiently?

The prompt was something like:

Write a program that takes as an input a list and returns the sum of all combinations of concatenating its elements pairwise.

For example, with the list [20, 5] this would be:

2020 + 205 + 520 + 55 = 2800

I still can't think of a way to do this without casting to string and back into int. The list comprehensions were previously nested for loops which performed worse but I still need more speed.

```
def concatenationsSum(a):
# turn into strings 
a = [str(i) for i in a]
# concat 
cartesian_product = [j + k for j in a for k in a]
# turn back into integers
total = [int(i) for i in cartesian_product]

return sum(total)
```

Comment: Think about the *value* that A & B each contribute to the sum from AB.  Then consider what all of the A's contribute, and finally all of the B's.

Comment: Can you rephrase that some other way? I don't understand.

Comment: From your example: 2020+205+520+55  = 20*100+20 + 20*10+5 + 5*100+20 + 5*10+5 = (20+5)*100 + (20+5)*10 + (20+5)*2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i tried some optimazation in your code, your main bottleneck here is the casting to str and back to int so i modified that part

```
def concatenationsSum(a):
   numDigits = {i: (10 ** (int(math.log10(i)) + 1)) for i in a}
   cpro = product(a, a)

   cartesian_product = [i * numDigits[x] + x for i, x in cpro]
   return sum(cartesian_product)
```

here you can see i changed a few parts, i added a dictionary to lookup for each number the number of digits it needs to multiply, an example would be 5 returns 10 so when you have 20 and 5 you can do `20 * digits[5] + 5 = 205` that speeds up the whole proccess.

also no need to use a double for loop in the list comprehension python itertools provides `product()` which return the cartesian product.

Testing done: with small lists about 8 elements i went from 4.6e05 to 3.1e05 average and with bigger lists of 5400 elements it got from 11.7 seconds average to 5.3 seconds. That's about double the speed.

Comment: Thank you, this is doing what @Scott Hunter was suggesting in the comment right?

From your example: 2020+205+520+55  = 20*100+20 + 20*10+5 + 5*100+20 + 5*10+5 = (20+5)*100 + (20+5)*10 + (20+5)*2

That I was doing with pen and paper but weak at maths. With the log to find the number of digits to multiply by. 

Did not know there was native support for cartesian product. Thank you.

Comment: well actually it does the first part but not the second part of the equality.